# Maven JSPC plugin running out of memory - anyway to fork?

Tags: maven, jsp

I'm trying to precompile a large amount of JSP pages using the `jspc-maven-plugin` (currently targetting a JBoss 4 install).  However, it seems to require a large amount of memory.  I need to launch maven with `-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m` in order to run to completion.  And even then, sometimes it fails.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jasig.mojo.jspc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>

            <!-- Use the Tomcat 6 JSP compiler -->
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jasig.mojo.jspc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jspc-compiler-tomcat6</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies> 
        </plugin>
```

Is there any way to run a JSPC compiler in a forked process to minimize the memory impact?  Is there a reason why the jspc compiler requires so much RAM?

Long term, I need to retarget JBoss 7 using the tomcat7 or tomcat8 jpsc compiler, but the memory issue remains the same.